# Issues using Oracle case function

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm trying to find the create a query that will return a set of staff's last name with their attached grade level (which is in another table with no foreign key relationship available with the staff one).

So far i have this but it is returning a "missing keyword" error on it. What is wrong with it?/ have i got my logic very wrong?

The last name and salary are in the staff/employee table.
The grade level is in a Job grades table.

```
    select last_name, salary, 
CASE grade_level
WHEN  lowest_sal >= 1000 THEN 'A'
WHEN lowest_sal >= 3000  THEN 'B'
WHEN lowest_sal >= 6000 THEN 'C'
WHEN lowest_sal >= 10000 THEN 'D'
WHEN lowest_sal >= 15000  THEN 'E'
ELSE 'F'
END 
FROM employees, job_grades 
WHERE department_id > 50;
```

Comment: Remove grade_level from case. Then there is a cross join between your tables - fix that

Comment: thankyou very much for the help i've now fixed it

Comment: You do have a problem with your CASE statement.  A lowest_sal value of 25,000 will always return 'A', because it is > 1,000.  To use a CASE like this, you'll need to reverse the order of the WHEN statements.

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in the `CASE` statement

Important thing - you are missing the `JOIN` conditions

```
SELECT LAST_NAME
    , SALARY
    , CASE 
        WHEN LOWEST_SAL >= 1000 THEN 'A'
        WHEN LOWEST_SAL >= 3000 THEN 'B'
        WHEN LOWEST_SAL >= 6000 THEN 'C'
        WHEN LOWEST_SAL >= 10000 THEN 'D'
        WHEN LOWEST_SAL >= 15000 THEN 'E'
        ELSE 'F'
    END AS GRADE_LEVEL
FROM EMPLOYEES
    JOIN JOB_GRADES 
        ON EMPLOYEES.ID = JOB_GRADES.EMP_ID 
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID > 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

To everyone possibly coming across this. I was slightly stupid in that i didn't need to use a CASE but if you need to then check out the above answer which provides the right answer.

Below is the code that worked for me. It basically is using the JOIN ON clause to join 2 tables without a relationship.

```
 select last_name, salary, grade_level
FROM employees JOIN job_grades ON (salary BETWEEN lowest_sal AND highest_sal)
WHERE department_id > 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just converted the SQL from Non-ANSI standard to ANSI standard. But the same could be achieved using non-ANSI standard. I see in your original query, you were trying to join to tables but did not define the joining criteria. It does not matter if there is a Relational Integrity (foreign Key) between those tables. While joining 2 tables, you must use the joining criteria.

```
                SELECT 
                LAST_NAME, 
                SALARY, 
                CASE GRADE_LEVEL
                    WHEN  LOWEST_SAL >= 1000 THEN 'A'
                    WHEN LOWEST_SAL >= 3000  THEN 'B'
                    WHEN LOWEST_SAL >= 6000 THEN 'C'
                    WHEN LOWEST_SAL >= 10000 THEN 'D'
                    WHEN LOWEST_SAL >= 15000  THEN 'E'
                ELSE 'F'
                END 
            FROM 
                EMPLOYEES EMP, JOB_GRADES JOBS --**MISSING Joining Criteria**
            WHERE
               DEPARTMENT_ID > 50;
```

In order to fix this, you need to have it like below

```
                SELECT 
                LAST_NAME, 
                SALARY, 
                CASE GRADE_LEVEL
                    WHEN  LOWEST_SAL >= 1000 THEN 'A'
                    WHEN LOWEST_SAL >= 3000  THEN 'B'
                    WHEN LOWEST_SAL >= 6000 THEN 'C'
                    WHEN LOWEST_SAL >= 10000 THEN 'D'
                    WHEN LOWEST_SAL >= 15000  THEN 'E'
                ELSE 'F'
                END 
            FROM 
                EMPLOYEES EMP, JOB_GRADES JOBS 
            WHERE
                 EMP.EMPLOYEES.ID = JOB_GRADES.EMP_ID --**This is the FIX**
               AND DEPARTMENT_ID > 50;
```